# mariadb 10.1.21 mysql.server start error on macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra

I have just installed mariadb 10.1.21 latest with brew.
here is what i got with command

```
> mysql.server start
```

or

> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.21/support-files/mysql.server start

whatever.

```
Starting MySQL
.170225 03:41:19 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/mac-615.err'.
170225 03:41:19 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
ERROR!
```

I do not know any reason why I cannot even start mysql daemon.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem today. What I did was just uninstalling both mariaDB and mysql.

Remember doing a backup of your DB's in case you need it.

Just run the following commands in you terminal:

For mysql:

```
brew remove mysql
```

For mariaDB:

```
brew remove mariadb
```

Then, remove mysql folders and files:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
vi /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Maybe, most of the folders and files won't exist, just to be sure they won't mess with the installation, do it.

After you have removed mysql and mariaDB files, run

```
brew cleanup
```

to ensure cache is gone.

Once it's done, you should be able to do a clean installation of mariadb with

```
brew install mariadb
```

Try your installation by running

```
mysql.server start
```

If hangs at starting, try restarting mysql with

```
mysql.server restart -f
```

By doing this, I was able to run mariadb, I hope it works for you.

Comment: Last two commands. `mysql.server start` and `mysql.server restart -f`. Not service.